# How to show /account/profile without pass the user like parameter?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-users

I want to show User profile in url `/account/profile`.
I have a detail class based view,

```
class UserDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    template_name = 'myuser/user_detail.html'
```

I have a error:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/profile/

Generic detail View UserDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

How can I charge the username without pass it like parameter in the url?

(ie: `/account/prifle/username`), the user is already authenticated. 
I see something similar here: http://programtalk.com/vs2/?source=python/12247/horas/apps/profiles/views.py but doesn't work to me. 
I tried modify `get_queryset`, `dispatch`, and nothing work, I don't know where can modify to get the right result.
Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is very bizarre and you should not follow it. Overriding `get_object` is the right idea in your case though; but that method should always actually return an object.

```
class UserDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: Thanks! I undestand a litte more every day.